# Increase/Decrease Font Size in iTerm2

Tags: macos, fonts, iterm2

**Issue:**
I use laptop on the go, and connect to external monitor when in the office. Given that the external monitor is very large, I need to increase fonts in the existing `iTerm2` window (usually one) and all tabs.
**Workaround:**
 I scale the fonts up 2-4 times (by pressing `Cmd-+`) for every tab I have open in a window (usually just one).

**Question:** Is there an easy way I could automate *increasing/decreasing font size* for all tabs of the current window? Or If I were to create two separate profiles, could I easily apply some profile to all currently open tabs in a window?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a really shitty and buggy way to automate this, but I'll post it anyway.

You can create a new profile in the iTerm2's preferences (the Profile pane). Let's call it "LargeFont". You can clone it from the default one by pressing **⌘=**.

Set the font size you want it to display in the newly created profile's Text pane.

[image]

Now here's the trick. You can't change either the font size or the profile of the terminal sessions using AppleScript (at least I haven't found a way), but you can execute commands in every session using AppleScript, and there's a custom escape sequence in iTerm2 that supports changing profiles for the session it was `echo`'ed in.

So, you can execute that:

```
echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=LargeFont\a"
```

in every opened session to change the terminal's profile to "LargeText".

Now we can use AppleScript to automate the execution for all opened sessions:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    repeat with theTerminal in terminals
        tell theTerminal
            repeat with theSession in sessions
                tell theSession
                    write text "echo -e '\\033]50;SetProfile=LargeText\\a'"
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Please note that it just writes the text (literally) into the each session, so if you have some text editor opened in one of your tabs - it won't work in it, and will paste the echo command in your code/configuration file instead. If you have a ping command running in one of the tabs - it won't work, too.
**You should make sure there is no interactive stuff running in any of your shells.**

You'll also have these commands left in your shell's history. You could bypass it by adding a space before the command itself (like `echo -e ...`), this works at least in zsh.

Here's the zsh function:

```
function iterm_change_profile() {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"iTerm\"
            repeat with theTerminal in terminals
                tell theTerminal
                    repeat with theSession in sessions
                        tell theSession
                            write text \" echo -e \\\"\\\\033]50;SetProfile=$1\\\\a\\\"\"
                        end tell
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell"
}
```

So you could use it like that:

```
iterm_change_profile LargeFont
```

There's also a drawback - when you change the profile from the one with the larger font to the smaller one, the iTerm's window resizes significantly.

But, again, it's a really shitty way.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. A similar thing I would like in iTerm2 would be to change also the Color Preset (Solarized-Dark and Solarized-Light depending on the surrounding light). I assume I will create a separate profile for that as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor. It worked nicely, although as you mentioned it is not the cleanest way. And you can uncheck the option to increase/decrease the window to resize when the font size changes in General Preferences -> "Adjust Window when changing font size".

Comment: just found out another thing: if i use the [TmuxIntegration](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration), changing font size works across all Tabs (tmux windows/panes). Color is still just per pane though.

Answer (score 27):

In the current iTerm2 (version 3.3.7), there's **View** > **Size Changes Update Profile** which solves the issue:

[image]

To change the font size regardless of profile, see [this iTerm2 issue](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/8318) where a script is provided.

Comment: Oh my gosh, we finally have sanity for default-font management in iTerm2 - many thanks for the point, @Borek.

Answer (score 1):

For version iTerm2, version - 3.4.17
You can use the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + **<kbd>+</kbd>**

Or you can go to

View -> Make Text Bigger
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change Igor's solution a bit; not sure why. Here's what worked for me:

```
function iterm_change_profile() {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"iTerm2\"
          tell current window
            repeat with aTab in tabs
                tell aTab
                    repeat with theSession in sessions
                        tell theSession
                            write text \" echo -e \\\"\\\\033]50;SetProfile=$1\\\\a\\\"\"
                        end tell
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
      end tell"
}
```